# javascript translation yml symfony2

Tags: symfony, client-side

I've many .yml file for the translation in my symfony webapp. Which is the right way to use this file clientside?

- Create a javascript.yml file
- Load all yml file (some parts are useless) even if I think could be inefficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Symfony 2.6, there is a `getMessages` method which can be used to dump the messages to a javascript file for client-side usage: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-improvements-for-the-translation-component#added-method-to-expose-collected-messages

```
$messages = $translator->getMessages('fr_FR');
json_decode($messages); // a javascript safe representation of the messages
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore (Symfony 3.0). The documentation (["Retrieving the Message Catalogue"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html#retrieving-the-message-catalogue)) now has this sample:

```
$catalogue = $translator->getCatalogue('fr_FR');
$messages = $catalogue->all();
while ($catalogue = $catalogue->getFallbackCatalogue()) {
    $messages = array_replace_recursive($catalogue->all(), $messages);
}
```